# Selecting a forms textbox via VBA DOM

Tags: excel, vba, dom

I have hundreds of cells of data in Excel that need to be pasted as raw text into a forums textbox. I have identified the textbox in the DOM and I can influence it's contents using it's value property. However I cannot simple set this value equal to a range of cells - so I will use a "bad" solution, SendKeys "^V". To do this i need to be able to select the textbox.

Already tried:

```
Set forum = IE.Document.getElementById("form1")
forum.Focus
SendKeys ("^v")
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I missed something simple:

```
forum.txtbox.Focus
```

I will leave my answer here in case anyone has this question in future as it's difficult to find answers on this topic on search engines due to the use of terms common in other applications. Using Focus will select the textbox.